# Finding the best order in a 2^n combinations

Tags: algorithm

I was requested to develop a simple software for my school which will be used in a manufacturing environment.

This is the scenario:

I'm given a list of sizes - each size reflect a board, so for instance I have a 24" x 30" board, 30" x 30", 30" x 48" and so on. These boards are a by-product of a process where they cut the raw material.

The raw material is presented in two different type of board sizes 60" x 120" and 48" x 96".

They wish to know the best way to cut the boards from the raw material - the "best" way is defined as the way with the least amount of raw material and residue. They also want to know the quantity of raw material which will be used, so for instance 30 boards of 60" x 120" and 3 of 48" x 96".

They are able to cut any board either horizontally or vertically, this means that a 24" x 30" can be cut either as a 24" x 30" or as a 30" x 24".

If I'm given a quantity of 50 boards overall (might be the same sizes) I can have 2^50 different combinations - this seems to be too long for me as they will be running the software on thousands of different board sizes.

I wonder if anyone knows an Algorithm that might fit this scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: Additional details are necessary. Firstly, are you allowed to do "guillotine" cuts only (all the way side to side) or are you allowed to do cuts that stop in the middle of board? Secondly, apparently they told you how many boards of each size you have to cut. Is it so?

Comment: Yes you are allowed to have only guillotine cuts. Yes, they do give you the qty and sizes which they need and you need to return the amount of boards from each size and the correct method to cut each board.

Comment: If you are restricted to guillotine cuts, then Wang's algorithm I mention in my answer will give you optimal guillotine solution. However, it might take a long time to find that solution. See the link to presentation in my answer for ways to speed up the algorithm by making it approximate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic simple algorithm for rectangular 2D cutting & packing problem is [Wang's algoritm](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~esicup/tiki-download_file.php?fileId=66)

However, pure Wang's algorithm is capable of producing the optimal *guillotine* cutting pattern, i.e. a pattern where all cuts travel all the way from one edge of remaining material to opposite edge. It can't produce a non-guillotine pattern as the following one

```
+---------+---+
|         |   |
+---+-----+   |
|   |     |   |
|   |     |   |
|   +-----+---+
|   |         |
+---+---------+
```

Yet, for many applications guillotine cutting patters are considered good enough. So, you might want to consider that algorithm (since it is very simple).

There are also approximate randomized algorithms based on Simulated Annealing technique (a detailed description can be found in [Simulated Annealing for VLSI Design](http://books.google.com/books/about/Simulated_Annealing_for_Vlsi_Design.html?id=1ldJR6BDjkIC) book (can't find it on the net), which are able to produce non-guillotine patterns.

In any case, finding precise solution for such problem usually requires considerable amount of computations to generate and analyze a great variety of possible variants, which makes it impractical in most cases. Most of the time people prefer to stick for good approximate/heuristic algorithms, which work much faster. Wang's algorithm can be customized with number of heuristic filters that speed up the search (at the risk of losing the optimal solution and replacing it with an "almost" optimal one).

Comment: Ok - seems like Wang Algorithm might work. Now, what happens if I have multiple options for the raw material basic size. As far as I understand Wang's is based on one size of basic L x W - I would need to have an array of those and then find the best possible combination.

Comment: I know this might be well late but do you perhaps have another resource for wang's algorithm-the one mentioned seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is that you could use the [Bin Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) algorithm to *pack* as many boards from one given piece of raw material.

You could also try out and use a [Genetic Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) to search for the best cutting pattern. The GA might (and might not) be as constantly effective as the Bin Packing Algorithm however you could stipulate a running time on the GA, so for instance, pick the best solution after a certain amount of time.

That being said however, I think that factories tend to do batch processes with material which is the same size, so maybe it might be best to allow (what probably is the slower) bin packing algorithm run prior to the actual cutting takes place.

Comment: This exactly the cutting stock problem in the 2D version. The only thing that I'm unable to understand is how to utilize the fact that I have various "raw material" sizes and not only one. This means that I might need to cut 500 different sizes of tables from more than ONE kind of raw material. I might have 10 different sizes to utilize to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem, and it is very similar to the [cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem). Also see the [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing).